# How to get the field type in a GraphQL schema directive (Node.js, graphql-tools)

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm using a schema directive which implements the `visitFieldDefinition` function of `SchemaDirectiveVisitor`. I want to know the type of the field defined in the schema and for example if the type is an array.

In the schema:

```
type DisplayProperties {
  description: StringProperty @property
  descriptions: [StringProperty]! @property
}
```

The property directive:

```
class PropertyDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    // how to check that field type is StringProperty?

    // how to find out that the field type is an array?
  }
}
```

Using Apollo server and graphql-tools.

Comment: Really helpful are the examples on the Apollo page: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-directives.html
Just reading the code gives a lot of insides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter passed to `visitFieldDefinition` is a `GraphQLField` object:

```
interface GraphQLField<TSource, TContext, TArgs = { [key: string]: any }> {
    name: string;
    description: Maybe<string>;
    type: GraphQLOutputType;
    args: GraphQLArgument[];
    resolve?: GraphQLFieldResolver<TSource, TContext, TArgs>;
    subscribe?: GraphQLFieldResolver<TSource, TContext, TArgs>;
    isDeprecated?: boolean;
    deprecationReason?: Maybe<string>;
    astNode?: Maybe<FieldDefinitionNode>;
}
```

So to get the type, you can just do:

```
const type = field.type
```

If the field is non-null, a list, or some combination of the two, you'll need to "unwrap" the type. You can check if any of the wrapper types are a List as you go:

```
const { isWrappingType } = require('graphql')

let isList = false
let type = field.type
while (isWrappingType(type)) {
  if (type.name === 'GraphQLList') {
    isList = true
  }
  type = type.ofType
}
```

Comment: The unwrap made the trick. Thanks for this helpful hint. I'm using TypeScript so the check for list can be done with `if (type instanceof GraphQLList) { isList = true; }`.

Answer (score 0):

We can check graphql types with

```js
const { GraphQLString } = require('graphql');

const type = field.type

if(field.type === GraphQLString) return 'string'
```

How I used this? I need to prefix the S3 object key with the S3 root URL so I create a directive to do that, it checks and returns for conditions string, and array. And the code.

```
const { SchemaDirectiveVisitor } = require('apollo-server');
const { defaultFieldResolver, GraphQLString, GraphQLList } = require('graphql');

class S3Prefix extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;
    field.resolve = async function (...args) {
      const result = await resolve.apply(this, args);

      if (field.type === GraphQLString) {
        if (result) {
          return [process.env.AWS_S3_PREFIX, result].join('');
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }

      if (field.type === GraphQLList) {
        if (result) {
          return result.map((key) => [process.env.AWS_S3_PREFIX, key].join(''));
        } else {
          return [];
        }
      }
    };
  }
}

module.exports = S3Prefix;
```